# Query to display the order of items

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get a list of fruits eaten by different people.

```
+-----------+
  ID   Name 
+----+------+
   1   Paul 
   2   John 
   3   Nick 
+----+------+
Table: users

+--------+--------+
  userID   Fruit
+--------+--------+
   1       Apple   
   2       Peach   
   2       Orange  
   2       Apple   
   3       Apple   
   3       Peach  
+--------+--------+
Table: eats
```

Now I can easily get a list of who ate what.  But if I want to know who ate what fruit 2nd?  Result would be:

```
+--------+----------+
  Name     Fruit
+--------+----------+
  John     Orange
  Nick     Peach
+--------+----------+
 Result

SELECT Name, Fruit FROM users, eats WHERE ID = userID ... ???
```

Comment: your releationship is wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @lanzz points out, you can't count on the order.  Maintaining a sequence would be expensive, but let's say you're storing the timestamp and the rows are returned in order...

Use a variable to remember how many rows you've seen for each name.  Iterate the variable while looking at the same person, and reset it when you hit a new person.  Then spit out only the records that have the desired sequence.  (This has the added benefit of being able to select the user's nth row for any value of n).

```
set @seen_name = null;
set @seq = 1;
select * from (
  SELECT Name, Fruit,
    case when @seen_name is null OR @seen_name != name then @seq := 1 else @seq := @seq + 1 end as seq_formula,
    @seen_name := name,
    @seq as seq
  FROM users, eats
  WHERE ID = userID
) foo
where seq = 2;
```

and voila:

```
+------+--------+-------------+--------------------+------+
| Name | Fruit  | seq_formula | @seen_name := name | seq  |
+------+--------+-------------+--------------------+------+
| John | Orange |           2 | John               |    2 |
| Nick | Peach  |           2 | Nick               |    2 |
+------+--------+-------------+--------------------+------+
```

Comment: Beautiful, that's exactly what I was looking for.  Indeed, my actual project does have a timestamp to get my rows in the proper order.  Thanks Alain, and everyone else who added to the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

This query ought to join the tables:

`SELECT eats.Fruit, users.Name FROM eats, users WHERE users.ID = eats.userID`

Comment: You are actually just repeating the query already included in the question.

Comment: @lanzz, there was no functioning query included in the question... just one broken, partial query. what are you talking about?? ;]

Comment: The second code block has the same query as yours in its last line, though without fully qualified column names (which is not actually necessary, as there are no ambiguous column names). Your answer does not add anything to it, you just strip out the ellipsis and the question marks (which are obviously not intended to be a part of the query as it would be executed, but an indication that the asker is wondering what else to add to the query)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rely on row order in a relational database without ordering the rows explicitly, as the order of the returned rows will vary as you delete and insert new records in your table. You will need to have an additional column, say `sequence`, that you will explicitly store the order of the fruits consumed. Then, it is straightforward to select the fruit with `sequence = 2`.